# vis.gam - How to add a simple colorbar in R?

Tags: r, visualization, gam, mgcv

I am trying to create a contour plot view of a gam model prediction using this code:

```
test <- data.frame(pop1 = rnorm(100), pop2 = rnorm(100), pop3 = rnorm(100))
library(mgcv)
mod_gam <-gam(pop1 ~ s(pop2) + s(pop3), data=test)
summary(mod_gam)
vis.gam(mod_gam, type='response', plot.type='contour')
```

My output is like this:[image]

How do I get a colorbar in the figure? I want to show the color scale corresponding with the contour lines.